# Check if attribute equals specific value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, list.phtml

I want to check that a *product attribute* equals a specified value in the product/view/list.phtml template and if so, display some html.

The current code gives **no result**. Can an edit be suggested to get it working in **Magento 2**.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
<?php if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getInStockMadeToOrder(), 'in_stock_made_to_order') == "This item is in stock") { ?>
  <div class="listing-labels in-stock"><p>In Stock</p></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: which value return for $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getInStockMadeToOrder(), 'in_stock_made_to_order')?

Comment: It would either be 'This item is in stock' or 'This item is made to order'

Comment: try with === , if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getInStockMadeToOrder(), 'in_stock_made_to_order') === "This item is in stock")

Comment: Try  $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('custom_attribute');

Comment: Neither options are working sadly.

Comment: OK so the reason the original code would not work is because the output of this attribute in product list is '94' for some reason. Not sure if you can shed any light Rakesh?

Answer (score 0):

you can add magento default functionality for checking product in-stock or out-of-stock, please check below function

```
<?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
     <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
<?php else: ?>
     <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, this is a custom attribute I am trying to find the value of. The default stock functionality is not what I am checking here.

Comment: Did you enabled from admin panel Used in Product Listing to Yes
From Admin Panel => Stores => Products(Attributes) => select attribute

Comment: Hi Yogesh, yes it is set up as Product Listing Yes